# How to hold position of every character from encoded string

Tags: java

I am trying to hold the position of every character (A-Z) from encoded string. I am unable to find out a way to implement it in Java.

Below is one example from C++ which I am trying to rewrite in Java.

```
map<Character,Integer> enc = new map<Character,Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < encoded.length(); i++)
{
  enc[encoded.charAt(i)] = i;
}
```

**Example below:**

I will have a Keyword which is unique e.g., Keyword is NEW. 
String will be formed by concatenating KEYWORD+Alphabets(A-Z which are not in the Keyword) e.g., **NEWABCDFGHIJKLMOPQRSTUVXYZ** (note that N,E and W are not repeated again in the above in the 26-Character string. Finally, I would like to hold the position of every character i.e., A-Z from the above string in bold.

Comment: What if the `String` has characters that aren't distinct? You just want them to be overwritten?

Comment: Let's say - We have AUBU CUDU as the string to be decoded. Here, "U" does repeat, however, every character will be decoded individually.

Comment: Yes but keys are unique

Comment: Yes Azro. keys are unique

Comment: So if you have "AUBU CUDU" and you put it in a map, what position do you want 'U' to have?

Comment: Position of U will depend of the keyword entered. E.g., Keyword is NEW (Here, all characters are unique) and later we will add A-Z (NEWABCDFG... and so on), Encoded string is something like AUBU CUDU. Based on Keyword+A-Z, AUBU CUDU will be decoded

Comment: I don't understand. What is a keyword, and what is the definition of "encoded"?

Comment: It is related to Cipher encoding and decoding.

Comment: This is information (unique keys, ciphers) that should be in the question description.

Comment: Apologies for missing out that info PhaseRush

Comment: You'd probably find that `Map<Character, Character>` would be more useful than `Map<Character, Integer>`. Then you can use the map to decode an encoded character into the plain-text character.

Comment: @DodgyCodeExceltion  Sure Dodgy will try. Thank you. Didn't crack it yet. Trying hard!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to handle duplicates letters , you can do as follows, it’ll only keep last occurrence for each letter :

```
Map<Character, Integer> enc = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < encoded.length(); i++) {
    enc.put(encoded.charAt(i), i);
}
```

——————-

To handle duplicates char, you can hold them in a List or concatenate them in a String for example (on the second I add a `filter` operation to remove spaces)

```
public static void main (String[] args) 
{
    String str = "AUBU CUDU";
    Map<Character, List<Integer>> mapList = 
        IntStream.range(0, str.length())
                 .boxed()
                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(i->str.charAt(i), i->Arrays.asList(i), (la,lb)->{List<Integer>res =new ArrayList<>(la); res.addAll(lb); return res;}));
    System.out.println(mapList);

    //{ =[4], A=[0], B=[2], C=[5], D=[7], U=[1, 3, 6, 8]}

    Map<Character, String> mapString =
        IntStream.range(0, str.length())
                 .boxed()
                 .filter(i->(""+str.charAt(i)).matches("[\\S]"))
                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(i->str.charAt(i), i->Integer.toString(i), (sa,sb)-> sa+sb ));
    System.out.println(mapString);

    //{A=0, B=2, C=5, D=7, U=1368}
}
```

[<kbd>Code Demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/9z4ldO)

Comment: This doesn't produce "duplicates" it just overwrites (erases) the previous value.

Comment: @PassionDevelopers  please edit your post , and explain a bit more I don’t understand what is missing to you

Comment: @Azro added more details to the post.

Comment: @PassionDevelopers  hum, you just need to set your text in the “str” variable, I don’t understand what is the problem

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding what youre saying, you want to map each character in a string to its index. However, Maps need a unique key for each entry, so your code wont work directly for strings which contain duplicate characters. Instead of using an Integer for each character, we'll use a List of Integers to store all the indexes which this character appears.

Here's how you would do that in java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Character, List<Integer>> charMap = new HashMap<>();

        String string = "aaabbcdefg";
        for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
            Character c = string.charAt(i);
            if (charMap.containsKey(c)) {
                List<Integer> positions = charMap.get(c);
                positions.add(i);
            } else {
                charMap.put(c, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(i)));
            }
        }

        for (Character c : charMap.keySet()) {
            System.out.print(c + ": ");
            charMap.get(c).forEach(System.out::print);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

output:

```
a: 012
b: 34
c: 5
d: 6
e: 7
f: 8
g: 9
```

Comment: I think the OP is actually talking about a substitution cipher (so all current answers are totally not what the OP wanted) but I'm waiting for a clarification.

Comment: Yes Dodgy. I am talking about substitution cipher (Keyword Cipher)

Comment: Yeah they later clarified in the comment chain. However, I defend my answer as it does perfectly answer the question.

Comment: PhaseRush, thanks for the answer. I have a query - In my example, I will have a string which is unique e.g., Keyword is NEW. Hence, String will be NEWABCDFGH... XYZ (note that E is left after D as it is already covered in NEW). Finally, I would like to hold the position of every character (Also note that all the characters finally formed will be unique)